# In this Linked List why it is not allowing me to run again and create another node what is the error in my code?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to make employee database using Linked list data structure but once I enter the value the option to run again is not available and also display function is not executes code stops before that I have checked the code sevearl times but I am not able to spot the error.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
    int Emp_No;
    node *next;
    node()
    {
        next=NULL;
    }
};

class Link_List
{
    public:
    node *head;
    
    Link_List()
    {
        head==NULL;
    }
    void create();
    void display();
};

void Link_List::create()
{
    node *temp,*p;
    int again;
    do
    {
        temp=new node();
        cout<<"Enter Employee No.: ";
        cin>>temp->Emp_No;
        if (head==NULL)
        {
            head=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p=head;
            while (p->next!=NULL)
            {
                p=p ->next;
            }
            p ->next=temp;
        }
        cout<<"Enter 1 to add more: ";
        cin>>again;
    } while (again==1);
}

void Link_List::display()
{
    node *p1;
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The linked list is empty"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        p1=head;
        while (p1!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Employee No:"<<p1 ->Emp_No<<endl;
            p1=p1->next;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Link_List emp1;
    emp1.create();
    emp1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the output it just allows me to enter the value once then wothout asking for next it ends and also display function is also not executed here:

```
PS E:\Programming\C++> cd "e:\Programming\C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ Linked_List.cpp -o Linked_List } ; if ($?) { .\Linked_List }
Enter Employee No.: 101
PS E:\Programming\C++>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo in `Link_List` constructor. it should be:

```
head=NULL;
```

not

```
head==NULL;
```

It seems to [work](https://onlinegdb.com/Yb4uQ0Cp1) after replacement.

TIP: Although statically scanning code with your eyes makes you think better; A debugger is an essential tool you need to adopt.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for making such a silly mistake to a question but I would learn from this and not do this again.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `head = NULL` while defining Link_list constructor as per your code.